# Вызов экшена контроллера при нажатии на кнопку submit_tag Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Нужно вызвать метод контроллера по нажатию на форму кнопки. 
Не могу понять как это сделать. 
Допустим есть контроллер Contacts. В нем методы Index, New, Create, Destroy. И написал свой метод Sent. 
Делаю кнопку <% submit_tag %>, в index.html.erb
По нажатию этой кнопки нужно выполнить код в методе Sent. Как обратится к этому методу?

Comment: А что в роутах? В config/routes.rb какие изменения добавлялись и как этот файл сейчас выглядит?

Comment: resources :main
  resources :contacts 
  resources :about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно добавить в файл config/routes.rb новый роут для метода `sent`

```
resources :contacts
get :sent, to: 'contacts#sent', as: sent
```

Убедиться в том, что роут добавлен можно в отечете команды `rails routes` (`rake routes` для старых версий)

```
rake routes | grep sent
sent GET    /sent(.:format)  contacts#sent
```

Первый столбец в отчете отображает алиас для path-хэлеперов, теперь вы можете ссылаться на роут при помощи `sent_path`. Последний столбец сообщает точку входа `ContactsController`, экшен `sent`.

Теперь хэлпер sent_path можно использовать во всех остальных тэгах (в зависимости от того, как формируете форму)

```
form_tag(sent_path, method: :get)
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать!

Comment: Ошибка No route matches {:action=>"sent", :controller=>"contacts"}, missing required keys: [:contact_id]. Довабил в routes.rb get :sent. Вызвал команду rake routes получил contact_sent GET    /contacts/:contact_id/sent(.:format) contacts#sent обращаюсь к методу <%= link_to "Sent", contact_sent_path %>

Comment: А форма у вас часом не методом POST отправляет?

Comment: Сделал так. Изменил роуты на следующее  resources :contacts do
    collection do
      get :sent
    end
  end и вот таким способом получилось достучаться до метода контроллера <%= form_tag sent_contacts_path, method: :get do %>. Спасибо за подсказки!